# Unable to render in flask interactive html outputs produced by R plotly package

Tags: python, r, flask, plotly

So I am using `python flask` to develop a web application that asks the user for data, analyse the data in the backend using BLAST and R, and outputs interactive HTML plots that are stored in a local location (Templates) and to be displayed to the user.

Everything up to R outputs runs smoothly. I have opened the HTML files and confirmed the R codes ran as expected and the produced graphs are interactive. However when I render these HTMLs through `flask` the browser returns a black page. Using `send_file` was also fruitless to display the plots. I have confirmed that the path to the Java scripts for the interactive plot are in the same folder.

Going through the developers tool console reads the following error:

```
htmlwidgets.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
datatables.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.dataTables.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Can someone please advise on how to successfully get the interactive R HTML outputs to show in `flask`?

Comment: Can you add some more info? How do you render HTML in flask? Do you use some template engine? Without some more info it is mostly wild guessing what went wrong.

Comment: Hi Maximilian, normally you'll return an html in flask with for example   @app.route('/software/')
 def software():
     return render_template ('software.html')
This returns an empty white screen on the browser with the produced htmls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `send_file` or `send_from_directory` you would also need to serve the JavaScript libraries needed for the plot, this might be the reason for the blank page.

The same is true for `render_template` but according to the error messages it seems more like that your JS libraries were also rendered as templates and some `<` or `>` character got added or removed.

Try the following snippet which works for me and perhaps gives you a good start.

---

A very simple R script to create a standalone HTML file with a `Plotly` plot. A file called `test.html` is created in the `/tmp` directory. All JavaScript libraries and CSS files are in `/tmp/test_files`.

```R
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

myData <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(3,2,1))
local_path <- '/tmp/'
ply <- plot_ly(myData, x = ~x, y = ~y, type='scatter', mode='markers+line')
saveWidget(widget=ply, file=paste(local_path, "test.html", sep=""), selfcontained = FALSE)
```

A minimal Flask server snippet to serve the plot and the JavaScript libraries is below. Starting flask and going in the browsesr to `http://localhost:5000/` would show the plot and provide all need libraries.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_from_directory
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def plotly():
    return send_from_directory('/tmp/', 'test.html')

@app.route('/test_files/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    return send_from_directory('/tmp/test_files', path)
```

Comment: Thanks Maximilian, I think this is exactly what I may need to solve my problem. However, it is not apparent to me from your code how the test.html file and test_files folder are linked using both routes as suggested. which route will i need to call on my browser to see the test.html properly display?             @app.route('/')
   def plotly():
       return send_from_directory('/tmp/', 'test.html')     returns the original issue

Comment: Awesome!!! it worked Max. Thanks a lot for your help. So I changed the test_files pass to the second route to @app.route('/<path:path>') and it worked beautifully. Thanks again